# Is it a good practice to have one RESTful resource for each database table?

Tags: api, database-design, django-rest-framework, relational-database, restful-architecture

What is the best way to map RESTful resources to database tables? When defining the architecture of a RESTful API, which criteria decides which resources to have and what is contained in each resource? Should each database table be mapped to a separate resource, or is this not best practice?

Answer (score 8):

Don't.

The API layer should not be tied to the data layer. That's an undesirable instance of strong coupling. The purpose of the database is to store data in a way that makes retrieval convenient. The purpose of the API is to get clients the information they need. It's highly unlikely that they will have the same structure. Furthermore, if you tightly couple them, you can't make changes to your database structure (such as renormalizing) without making a breaking API change.